# High voltage OP amplifier circuit analize

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-source

I revised my previous hand drawing schematic to a clear one.

1. As discuss, Block A seem to be a non-inverting amplifier. But not same with classic non-inverting OPA, the input is at inveting-input at OP, is this works?
   Or it's a schmitt trigger?
2. Block D seems to be a current source, How to calculate the current Id?
3. How to analyze block B & C?  What is C1 function?

The image from circuit lab looks a litter small. I attached a bigger on pic.

Sorry for many questions, I'm really new to analog circuit.

Thanks a lot for your patience.

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwXVOK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Stick with the original question. Duplicates are closed as you see.

Answer (score 0):

Q1 runs as Pchannel common-gate, pulling up on gate of the Q2 Nchannel with source at -180 volts.

U1,Q1,Q2 are a non-inverting feedback loop. If my words: Q1 is Pch, Q2 is Nch, are correct. Thus only Q2, wired common-source, is inverting and no Schmitt action occurs. Is OpAmp (+) sign properly located?

Predict the current? by assuming Von of Q3 is zero volts, thus all the zener voltage is across R12 the 5Kohm in the source. Current is 10v/5Kohm = 2mA.

Comment: Yes, the OPA (+) is correct located. The actual circuit act like a voltage amplifier, linearly amplify Vin. I'm really confuse for the OPA that with a positive feedback.

Comment: The current of Id is 1.1mA, how to check the Vgs to calculate correct Id in MOSFET datasheet?

Answer (score 0):

Years ago I developed a controlled-slew pin-driver, using negative-feedback.
This circuit is negative-feedback.
The SlewRate will be (Q = C*V, differentiated into I = C*dV/dT,) arranged into dV/dT = I/C; we have 2mA/100pF *if* we ignore the Nch mosfet C_gate_drain.
The SlewRate would be 2e-3/1e-10 == 10^7 volts per second, or 1 volt in 100nS or 100 volts in 10 microseconds.

The Nch C_gate_drain may be huge (1,000pF) or tiny. Use the same math, given a datasheet numver for C_gate_drain.

I dare presume the 10Kohm resistor in series with C1.....is to stabilize the feedback.